# Combining Gulp Tasks

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have several Gulp tasks that I'm running. Although it's perfectly fine running them the way that I have it, I'm re-using the same code over and over and and I feel like I can trim some fat off.

```
gulp.task('task1', function(){
    return gulp.src('bower_components/file1.js')
        .pipe(concat('file1-min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('javascripts'));
});

gulp.task('task2', function(){
    return gulp.src('bower_components/file2.js')
        .pipe(concat('file2-min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('javascripts'));
});

gulp.task('task3', function(){
    return gulp.src('bower_components/file3.js')
        .pipe(concat('file3-min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('javascripts'));
});
```

I have quite a few of those tasks so hopefully something like this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but please try.

```
gulp.task('combined', [
  'task1',
  'task2',
  'task3',
]);
```

Run it with `gulp combined`

Answer (score 0):

Try using gulp-param: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-param

```
var gulp = require('gulp-param')(require('gulp'), process.argv);
```

This will allow you to pass the parameter from the cli like so:

```
$ gulp task --id 1
$ gulp task --id 2
$ gulp task --id 3
```

Then you can concatenate the *id* to the strings

```
gulp.task('task', function(id){
    return gulp.src('bower_components/file' + id + '.js')
        .pipe(concat('file' + id + '-min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('javascripts'));
});
```